# Custom modal with cancel and send again button

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, modal

[image]

I need to show a custom kind of toast message where based on a fieldValue I am trying to show a modal which will have a cancel and a 'Continue' button. On cancel I want to close the modal and on 'continue' I want to render a docusign page.

Here is my code:

1. Main component code:

```
in cmp:
<aura:attribute name="sendAgain" type="Boolean" default='false'/>


controller:
if(senderNotification == true) {
                var message = 'DocuSign has already been sent!!';
                component.find("child").docuSignShowToastModel(sendAgain);
                if(sendAgain == true){
                    helper.getDocuSignUrl(component, event);
                } /*else if(sendAgain == false) {
                    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                    urlEvent.setParams({
                        "url": "/lightning/page/home"
                    });
                    urlEvent.fire();
                }*/
            } else {
                helper.getDocuSignUrl(component, event);
            }
```

```
<aura:component >

    <aura:attribute name="message" type="string"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sendAgainV" type="Boolean" default='false' access="public"/>

    <aura:method name="docuSignShowToastModel" action="{!c.showDocusignExistsToast}" access="public">
        <aura:attribute name="sendAgainV" type="Boolean" access="public"/>
    </aura:method>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sendAgainV}">
        <section aura:id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!-- ###### MODAL BOX HEADER Start ######-->
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                          onclick="{! c.closeModel }"
                                          alternativeText="close"
                                          variant="bare-inverse"
                                          class="slds-modal__close"/>
                </header>
                <!--###### MODAL BOX BODY Part Start######-->
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <p><b>docusign has been sent already, please click on send now if you wish to send again.</b></p>
                </div>
                <!--###### MODAL BOX FOOTER Part Start ######-->
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning:button variant="neutral" 
                                      label="Cancel"
                                      title="Cancel"
                                      onclick="{! c.closeModel }"/>
                    <lightning:button variant="brand" 
                                      label="Send Again"
                                      title="Send Again"
                                      onclick="{! c.sendAgain }"/>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
    </aura:if>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
</aura:component>
```

I thought of changing the parent attribute value, I think we can't do that, how can I achieve this kind of functionality

```
({
    showDocusignExistsToast : function(component, event, helper) {
        var params = event.getParam('arguments');
        component.set("v.sendAgainV", params.param1);
        console.log('send again value*********** ' + params.param1);
        console.log('send again value::::::::: ' + component.get('v.sendAgainV'));
    },

    closeModel : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.sendAgainV", true);
        var confirmmodal = component.find('myModal');
        $A.util.addClass(confirmmodal, 'slds-hide');
    },

    sendAgain: function(component, event, helper) {
        // Display alert message on the click on the "Like and Close" button from Model Footer 
        // and set set the "isOpen" attribute to "False for close the model Box.

        component.set("v.sendAgainV", true);
    },

})
```

right now I am just getting a blank black screen, is it possible to somehow set the 'sendAgain' value so that based on that I can render my docusign url on click of 'send again' button.
Or what is the other better way of doing it.

Comment: from where are you calling `doocuSignShowToastModel`? Can you show parent component code?

Comment: @salesforce-sas  its in the first code snippet- component.find("child").docuSignShowToastModel(sendAgain); - in the parent component

Answer (score 0):

**added based on comments**

Since `sendAgainV` is already true, setting it to true again will not work as there is no change in value. Ofcourse, you can set it to false and immediately set it to true but this is not recommended because that will create a duplicate element in aura_prod.js file (this is a bug). Instead you can do below:

1. You can create a [component event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_example.htm).
2. Register that event in child component:

   ```
   <aura:registerEvent name="cmpEvent" type="c:ceEvent"/>
   ```
3. Invoke that in JS method:

```
    sendAgain: function(component, event, helper) {
        var cmpEvent = cmp.getEvent("cmpEvent");
        cmpEvent.setParams({
            "message" : "A component event fired me. It all happened so fast. Now, I'm here!" 
        });
        cmpEvent.fire();
    },
```

and in parent component:

```
<aura:handler name="cmpEvent" event="c:ceEvent" action="{!c.yourParentMethod}"/>
```

and in `yourParentMethod`, you can do the action of `helper.getDocuSignUrl(component, event);`

---

In Parent component:

```
component.find("child").docuSignShowToastModel(sendAgain);
```

Here `sendAgain` is false by default. You should have that as true to render in child ocmponent.

Also in child component method `showDocusignExistsToast`:

```
component.set("v.sendAgainV", params.param1);
```

Here you are actually getting the attribute `sendAgainV` and not `param1`. You should have:

```
component.set("v.sendAgainV", params.sendAgainV);
```

Comment: for this ``` if(sendAgain == true){
                    helper.getDocuSignUrl(component, event);
                } ```  how do I make my sendAgain attribute true on click of the send again button in child component

Comment: The problem is that button will not even be rendered for clicking on it. First, you need to render the modal from parent component

Comment: I am able to see the modal. added a picture

Comment: added in answer

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment, really appreciate your help, can you please help me understand it more, as I am not very clear with this solution. I need to show this modal kind of message with a cancel and send again button, so I need to render that based on the senderNotificaion field being true.if I create this event and fire it from child, would I have the control to show the modal from parent component. how would I fire that event from child, I want to render this modal msg with cancel and sendAgain button as and when my 'SenderNotification' field is true.